# Looking for first empty row + updating values in column up until last not empty row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets I'm trying to create a script that looks up what the first empty row is (based on values in column `A`).
After finding that row (row 10 for example), I want the script to populate cells `B2:B9` with the value: `'Example'`

I've looked at the following script, but can't seem to modify it to work in the way described above:

```
  function getFirstEmptyRow() {
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var column = spr.getRange('A:A');
  var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
  var ct = 0;
  while ( values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
  }
  return (ct);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find the first index of a given element in an array. Then [setValue("Example")](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)) to the first row/cell in the column you want it in and use [copyValuesToRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyValuesToRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) to fill the desired range with that value.

```
function getFirstEmptyRow() {
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spr.getSheets()[0];
  var column = spr.getRange('A:A');

  // get all data in one call & flatten array
  var values = column.getValues().join().split(","); 

  // find first empty row
  var empty_row = values.indexOf("");
  var example_range = sheet.getRange("B2");

  // set the first value
  example_range.setValue("Example");

  // copy that value in all rows in col b until the first empty row index
  example_range.copyValuesToRange(sheet.getSheetId(), 2, 2, 2, empty_row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but maybe you should check [Sheet.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)